# how can i make a little rotation and back and why is my object vibrating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a spacegame with 3 lines and when the spaceship moves to an other lane it should make a little rotation to the side and go back to the normal position.Furthermore it "vibrates" because the x coordinate is fluctuating in an little interval. how can I fix this?

heres my code.

```
public class NewMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float LANE_DISTANCE = 5f;
    
    //Movement
    private CharacterController controller;
    private float verticalVelocity;
    private float speed = 7f;
    private int desiredLane = 1; // 0 = Left, 1 = Middle, 3 = Right

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Gather the input on which lane we should be
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            MoveLane(false);
       
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            MoveLane(true);
            
        // Calculate where we should be in the future
        Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position.z * Vector3.forward;
        if (desiredLane == 0)
            targetPosition += Vector3.left * LANE_DISTANCE;
        else if (desiredLane == 2)
            targetPosition += Vector3.right * LANE_DISTANCE;

        // Let's calculate our move delta
        Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
        moveVector.x = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized.x * speed;
        moveVector.z = speed;

        //Move the Ship
        controller.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);              
    }

    private void MoveLane(bool goingRight)
    {
        desiredLane += (goingRight) ? 1 : -1;
        desiredLane = Mathf.Clamp(desiredLane, 0, 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please put more suitable tag in your question when you are ask question in stackoverflow, 
for more information about how to ask good question please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is where modern motion calculation comes into play, because the interval between each frame drawing is not necessarily the same, the motion of the game will fluctuate in speed. To counteract this, one simply calculates how long it has been since the previous drawing operation, and calculates how far the game should have moved in that time. This requires calling the system's `nanotime` function at the end of your drawing loop and storing it, then when you next get to the drawing stage you move everything by `time * distance moved in 1ns` or a similar unit